# The word "Americans" can't be an adjective, but "Scots" can be. — Why is it so?

Tags: adjectives, history

We can use "American" as an adjective but not "Americans" because "Americans" is a plural noun.
By this logic, we should use "Scot" as an adjective but not "Scots".
The word "Scots" in the role of an adjective seems very strange to me because it doesn't look like an ordinary adjective, it looks like a plural noun.
I'm very curious about whether there is a reasonable explanation why we use the adjective "Scots" rather than "Scot".

Comment: It _can_ be a plural noun (_a Scot_ = a Scottish person) as well as a variant of the adjective _Scottish_.

Answer (score 2):

In any language, there are usually several ways that adjectives for countries are formed... and there are usually exceptions.

In English some exceptions are Holland -> Dutch, Barbados -> Bajan.

For probably the majority of countries we add -n or -an or -ian: America ->American, Kenya -> Kenyan, Ghana -> Ghanaian, Fiji -> Fijian, etc.

There are also quite a few countries that take -ese: Senegal -> Senegalese, Nepal -> Nepalese, Japan -> Japanese

For arab countries, the adjective is formed by adding -i, mimicking the arabic letter ي which is often used to form arabic adjectives: Yemen ->Yemeni, Oman -> Omani, Emirates -> Emirati

For some countries, we remove the last few letters and and add -ish: England -> English, Poland -> Polish, Spain -> Spanish. The adjective for Scotland is derived in this way, giving Scottish.

According to [Etymology Online](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Scots), Scots is derived indirectly from Scottish -> Scottis -> Scots.

A similar contraction occurs with France, where Frankish (which is no longer used) has changed to French.

I don't see any logic which requires Scots to lose a further letter (s). There are about ten thousand adjectives that end with an s, so why should Scots lose its s?

A very similar word is the adjective nuts- an informal word meaning crazy. A person who is nuts is a nut, in the same way as a person who is Scots is a scot.

Comment: You wrote that the adjective "Scots" is derived from "Scottish". But then why did the word "Scottish" not lead to the creation of the adjective "Scot" (without "s")? It would have been much more correct in terms of what ordinary English adjectives are supposed to look like.

Comment: @Loviii You are making the mistake of assuming that somebody made a logical decision about this: language doesn't work like that. Read the  Etymology Online article: it explains the process that led from Scottish to Scots.

Comment: I did read it even before creating the original post.

Comment: Etymonline mentions the alternative form "Scotch" which may have been an influence. There's also "[Erse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Erse)", an old name for Irish with a similar etymology, which also ends with an /s/ sound though it's spelt differently.

Comment: There's also Manks, an old spelling of [Manx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manx_language), which are both derived from "Mannish", and Afrikaans (from Dutch Afrikaansch). So not really all that strange.